# nunjucks wont render template JavaScript(Html)

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

Im trying to render a template using nunjucks!

As seen in the screenshot I'm rendering the faucet.html from inside index.js
I cant render it though I get a error

Code

```
app.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  //return res.send(nunjucks.render('index.html', {error: "Faucet currently under upgrade and maintenance, come back later", success: false}));
  return res.send(nunjucks.render("faucet.html", {}));
});
```

Error

```
/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:290
        err = new Error('template not found: ' + name);
              ^

Error: template not found: faucet.html
    at createTemplate (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:290:15)
    at next (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:330:7)
    at handle (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:329:11)
    at /home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:339:9
    at next (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:328:7)
    at Object.asyncIter (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:334:3)
    at Environment.getTemplate (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:321:9)
    at Environment.render (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:360:10)
    at Object.render (/home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/node_modules/nunjucks/index.js:92:14)
    at /home/runner/ForestgreenOldDataset/js/index.js:85:28
```

[image: ScreenShotOfFIles]

Comment: how nunjucks suppose to know that you have templates in src folder one level down and one level up from current directory?

Comment: Well could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nunjucks.configure([path], [opts]);` to tell nunjucks that your templates live at path `../src`.

[documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure)

```js
nunjucks.configure('../src', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app
})
```